# Do 2 vortices next to each other have any attracting force?

Tags: vortex

Do 2 vortices next to each other have any attracting force?

Say you have 2 tip vortex sized vortices next to each other. Will they have any sort of attracting force toward each other? If they do, why is that?

(For simplicity's sake, say a spacing between the 2 vortices of whatever makes sense for explaining)

Thanks and happy new years!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has been asked and answered before. The author is advised to use the search function and to actually read the multiple answers.

Comment: @PeterKämpf would you mind telling me which question has answered this one? I mean I always search for similar questions before I ask them

Comment: Was this question closed because off topic or duplicate? If off topic then I'd propose to reopen it because it's a legitimate aerodynamics question. If duplicate then I don't see any link to the duplicated one...

Comment: @sophit I’m not sure of any other questions that answer this specific one. I am clueless as to why this got marked as off topic.

Comment: @Wyatt: Frog's comment to the answer of [How do 2 vortices (or more) combine when they are near each other?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102290/how-do-2-vortices-or-more-combine-when-they-are-near-each-other)

Comment: @Peter oh I remember reading that comment. It helped a lot, but it didn't seem like a full answer, so I thought I'd ask a separate one. If the answer to my question is as simple as that comment explains it as, then I get closing this question.

Comment: @Wyatt A vortex is not a physical entity - it is just a flow pattern which we separate from the rest of the flow and give a name to. Please stop thinking of it as an object separate from the rest of the air.

Comment: @PeterKämpf yeah, that helps to think of it as just a flow pattern. Thanks for your help!